# Migrating a domain name from Yahoo to Google apps or any other free service provider?

Tags: domain-name

I just bought a domain from yahoo and realized that I can't opt out of its auto renewal.

Now, I want to migrate my domain name to any other service provider,
which doesn't charge me for the first year(for which I have already paid).

Is it possible with Google Apps?

If yes, how?

If no, then what are the options I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *transfer* your domain name to another registrar, but you will have to pay a fee, which will extend your registration period by another year.

Google Apps offers the possibility to register a domain name to use their services with but they do this partnered with GoDaddy, as GA isn't a registrar.

I'd really recommend going with NameCheap on this one. Easy to use service and great pricing.